# Обновляется окно при клике, как убрать?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт

```
function shops(elt) {
    $('#'+$(elt).data('id')).fadeIn();
};
$(function($) {
    $('.popup-order').find('.close').on('click',function() {
        $('.popup-order').fadeOut();
    });
    $('.popup-order').on('click',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('popup-order')) $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Он привязан к ссылке:

```
<a href="" class="close" title="Закрыть"></a>
```

При клике на ссылку в появившемся окне происходит обновление страницы и окно закрывается. Необходимо убрать обновление страницы при клике.

1. Навесить return false не сработало
2. Убрать href отключает полностью ссылку, как и если прописать ссылке ##
3. Заменить ссылку на span не работает
4. Навесить onclick сразу в ссылке с отменой не работает
5. Указать e.preventDefault(); не работает
6. Указать javascript:void(0) не работает

Comment: *"Он привязан к ссылке:"* --- каким образом? Нужно показать этот код.......... *"При клике на ссылку в появившемся окне"* --- что ещё за окно? Почему кода окна нет? .....................*"происходит обновление страницы"* --- Показанный код явно ничего нигде не обновляет................. Предоставьте полноценный код для воспроизведения. На текущий момент тут ничего ни  с чем не связано и не соответствует описанию

Comment: *"Убрать href отключает полностью ссылку, как и если прописать ссылке ##"* --- а разве это проблема? Если обработкой занимается скрипт, то и **никакие ссылки тут не нужны**

Comment: пробуй **event.preventDefault();**

Comment: Указать e.preventDefault(); не работает

Comment: Если вы не предоставите полноценный воспроизводимый пример, то вам больше ничем не сможет помочь.

Comment: Возможно, у вас не работает `e.preventDefault()` потому как в событие клика вы не передаете тот самый **е**, который является Event'ом?

Answer (score -1):

Вы не дали полный пример кода, и остаётся только гадать, почему у вас не работают решения, которые обязаны работать. Одной из причин, по которой `e.preventDefault();` не работает, может быть то, что событие не передается в функцию обработчика событий или оно не корректно определяется в вашем коде.

Вот примерное решение, на основе вашего кода:

```
$(function($) {
    $('.popup-order').find('.close').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('.popup-order').fadeOut();
    });
    $('.popup-order').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('popup-order')) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});

function shops(elt) {
    elt.preventDefault(); 
    var id = $(elt.target).data('id'); // Если elt - это event объект, иначе используйте $(elt).data('id')
    $('#' + id).fadeIn();
};
```

Если вы используете `onclick="shops(this);"` в HTML, вам нужно будет изменить способ передачи события и обработки, возможно, передавать event в shops функцию и обрабатывать его аналогично.